# Improving performance on a visjs network with 440 nodes (all images)

Tags: javascript, json

We're using http://visjs.org/ to visualise a network of 440 people. Each node is an image (shape:image) and we're experiencing some pretty heavy lag when the browser is zoomed out to view the network in it's entirety.

Is there anything that can be done to improve this, or is it simply a matter of reducing the data set or restricting the zoom so that not too many images are shown at any one time?

Thanks!

Matt

Comment: Searching also for performance improvements

Comment: Hey ThaDafinser, if it helps we used an SVG in the end and added soom zoom and pan controls (if I remember I think it was exported from a GUI we used to create it). It's way quicker. If you really want to use visjs, you may be able to make use of pixi.js to process through the GPU. We never looked into this in the end but have used pixi since on other projects.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Will give it a try